# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Message: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: .net, iis

Short of restarting our server, is there anyway we can get this memory released and our website up and running. Below is a trace from the event viewer

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>   Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/17/ROOT Process ID: 14352 Exception:
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Message: Not enough storage is
>   available to process this command StackTrace: at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32
>   exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name,
>   IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks) at
>   MS.Win32.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper..ctor() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher() at
>   ISC.MapDotNetServer.MapPrintSupport.BaseTileRequestorResolver.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>
> steps taken,  IISRESET Application pool recycle

Have not killed the process through taskmgr yet, that is a last resort.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but would it be possible to recycle the app pool connected with the website? It might give some memory back without having to resort to a reboot.

Comment: tried, i guess you posted before i updated my question

Comment: @george9170 - Yeah, didn't read your Q which included the steps taken.

Comment: Just had a read of this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978735.aspx - could it be that you are running out of disk space? Or could it be the page file isn't big enough? Might not be RAM related as such.

Comment: 800 gigs of free space and 32 gigs of ram. The machine has enough free ram.

Comment: The error seems to refer to a map server.  any chance that one is full and the error is bubbling up?

Comment: The mapserver is just an app name. We would like to free this memory and then hunt for the problem later. The only solution is to restart our server which is hosted somewhere else and hope it comes back up. I was wondering if anyone knew a different way of freeing this memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was bringing down the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This might relate:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620588